# FTP Downloading a file while its upload is in progress

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, download

I have a windows service (VB.NET) which downloads files from a server after a specific interval. What happens if it try to download a file when its upload is in progress?

If it creates some problem, how to cope with this situation?

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the FTP server.
Most servers will probably throw an access denied exception when downloading the file, which you can catch.  (Catch a `WebException` and look at the response and/or the status code)

Comment: +1 Yup; they'll return the appropriate FTP error code, which will be contained in the WebException